# Mail function sending blank values

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send an email to user account using php `mail()` function.The mail is sent successfully but the issue is that it is sending me blank emails with no values in them! The code for the contact page that sends the email is as follows:-

```
<form  class="contact-form"  method="POST" action="sendemail.php">
                  <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span5">
                        <label>First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="input-block-level" required="required" placeholder="Your First Name" name="name">
                        <label>Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="input-block-level" required="required" placeholder="Your Last Name" name="lname">
                        <label>Email Address</label>
                        <input type="text" class="input-block-level" required="required" placeholder="Your email address" name="email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="span7">
                        <label>Message</label>
                        <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="input-block-level" rows="8" name="message"></textarea>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large pull-right" value="Send Message" />
                <p> </p>

            </form>
```

and sendemail.php page code is as follows:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $status = array(
        'type'=>'success',
        'message'=>'Email sent!'
    );

    $name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
    $email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
    $subject = "An enquiry sir"; 
    $message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 

    $email_from = $email;
    $email_to = 'email@email.com';

    echo $body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

    $success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

    echo json_encode($status);
    die;
   ?>
```

Why is the output I get blank in my email id, for example:

> Name:
>
> Email:
>
> Subject:
>
> Message:

P.N: I am using here a nova template theme.

The form is being submitted via AJAX using the following JavaScript:

```
var form = $('.contact-form');
form.submit(function () {
  $this = $(this);
  $.post($(this).attr('action'), function(data) {
    $this.prev().text(data.message).fadeIn().delay(3000).fade‌​Out(); 
  },'json');
  return false; 
});
```

Comment: Is `sendemail.php` also the script that displays the form?

Comment: The form gets posted with empty inputs?  Try `isset($_POST['name'])` etc...

Comment: @Barmar no sir it is an different script

Comment: done any basic debugging, like `var_dump($_POST)` to see what PHP's receiving? Plus, you have an `lname` field, but never bother handling that in PHP.

Comment: Are you using AJAX to submit the form? There's probably a problem in the Javascript code that does this.

Comment: @Barmar yeah the json status is used to echo if the mail has been send

Comment: have you forgot to paste some code?? where is the subject field that you are retrieving? have you tried using die() with your values here..??

Comment: @RohitS no rohit i have not but thanks for notifying me of a mistake i will edit it in the question now

Comment: @AbhishekJoshi Post the Javascript code, that's probably where the problem is. Check the Network tab in the browser console to see what parameters you're sending.

Comment: @barmar i am using a template here however going to the console of firefox and checking for any error there it notify me of 3 errors but those are in jquery file

Comment: Did you go into the Network tab to see the AJAX parameters?

Comment: @barmar those error are as follows:Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead[Learn More]jquery-1.9.1.min.js:1
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.

Comment: Those are all just warnings, they shouldn't cause problems.

Comment: @AbhishekJoshi ok also let us know what you get in '$body' var....you are also not checking the value of $success for mail being sent or not just echoing success do check it first and then go ahead...

Comment: @RohitS it gives me an output like these Name: 

Email: 

Subject: An enquiry sir

Message: Name: 

Email: 

Subject: An enquiry sir

Message:

Comment: Your ajax javascript must not be sending the form data correctly, here is a demo of your code running correctly using regular html form submission (not ajax): https://public-klebestift.c9users.io/ . You need to examine the ajax request in the network tab of developer tools and see what is being sent.

Comment: This is what you need to be looking for when we say examine the ajax request in the network tab of developer tools: http://screencast.com/t/kObKaEms4R but the entry you are looking for in the "Name" column should say "sendemail.php"

Comment: @Luke i have seen it and it does not give me any output like of Form Data

Comment: That's the problem then. It's probably doing a GET instead of a POST. If you could screenshot what it does have and add it to the question that would help. So would providing the code that submits the form.

Comment: @Luke here is the link of the snapshot https://s15.postimg.org/efdijzkxn/snipshot.png

Comment: If there was a 'Form Data' section, you'd have to scroll down in the lower right pane to see it. It's submitting to `index.html` and not to `sendemail.php` and in that case you should get no email at all. The code you have posted up to this point works fine, without providing the code that actually submits the form, no one can help you.

Comment: @Luke it is showing me a no parameter send for these request. and sorry about the index.html i was just trying to check if there was some else error well never mind here is the jquery code of the form which i found in the template in main.js file var form = $('.contact-form');
  form.submit(function () {
   $this = $(this);
   $.post($(this).attr('action'), function(data) {
   $this.prev().text(data.message).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
  },'json');
  return false;
 });

Answer (score 0):

the form submission code is not submitting the form data. Here is the code you provided:

```
var form = $('.contact-form');
form.submit(function () {
  $this = $(this);
  $.post($(this).attr('action'), function(data) {
    $this.prev().text(data.message).fadeIn().delay(3000).fade‌​Out(); 
  },'json');
  return false; 
});
```

and this is what it should be:

```
var form = $('.contact-form');
form.submit(function () {
  $this = $(this);
  $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
    $this.prev().text(data.message).fadeIn().delay(3000).fade‌​Out(); 
  },'json');
  return false; 
});
```

Answer (score -3):

Remove the `echo` from the line that defines $body
From this...

```
   echo $body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email
```

To this...

```
   $body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email
```

Comment: Why would that help? It assigns the variable and then echoes it.

Comment: the vairables are not getting assigned, only the defined strings...  There is also a header call in the script, and echoing would cause the output already started fun.

Comment: `echo $var = value;` is the same as `$var = value; echo $var;`.

Comment: The `header()` call is before the output, so he won't get that warning.

Comment: The only problem this will cause is that parsing the JSON on the client will fail. But that has nothing to do with the contents of the mail.